# Google Cloud SQL and Triggers

Tags: magento, google-cloud-sql

I know this has been asked before. However after following the suggestion in the post "[Triggers cloud sql 2nd generation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39221261/triggers-cloud-sql-2nd-generation)" I am still getting the `ERROR 1227 Access Denied Requires SUPER USER Privileges`
My application is Magento EE 1x. I have disabled Binary Logging, I have disabled backups altogether, I don't do any replication. I have set the `log_bin_trust_function_creators` flag to `ON` And I am still getting the error. 
Here is an example of my code from my magento backup that I am trying to restore into the google cloud SQL gen2. In this process I have two sql backups the data and the triggers, data restored fine it's the file of all the triggers that won't import.

```
USE `dev_magento`;
/*!50003 SET @saved_cs_client      = @@character_set_client */ ;
/*!50003 SET @saved_cs_results     = @@character_set_results */ ;
/*!50003 SET @saved_col_connection = @@collation_connection */ ;
/*!50003 SET character_set_client  = utf8 */ ;
/*!50003 SET character_set_results = utf8 */ ;
/*!50003 SET collation_connection  = utf8_general_ci */ ;
/*!50003 SET @saved_sql_mode       = @@sql_mode */ ;
/*!50003 SET sql_mode              = '' */ ;   
DELIMITER ;;
/*!50003 CREATE*/ /*!50017 DEFINER=`someuser`@`remote_IP`*/ /*!50003 TRIGGER trg_catalog_category_entity_after_insert
AFTER INSERT
ON catalog_category_entity FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
INSERT IGNORE INTO `enterprise_url_rewrite_category_cl` (`entity_id`)
VALUES (NEW.`entity_id`);
INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalog_category_product_cat_cl` (`category_id`) VALUES (NEW.`entity_id`);
INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalog_category_flat_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`entity_id`);

END */;;
```

Some have posted that importing from the CLI has worked it's unclear if that's using googles tools or mysql? Using the mysql command to import does not work as it results in the same error. 
Some insight to this would be very helpful and thanks to Vadim for his post on disabling binary logging and setting the `log_bin_trust_function_creators` to `TRUE`, I wish those suggestions would work in my case.

Comment: DEFINER is what requires super privileges, try removing it

Comment: Thanks Vadim that worked.