# Import created mysql trigger file on Google Cloud console

Tags: mysql, triggers, google-cloud-storage

I have already created some mysql triggers on my local phpmyadmin and exported, Now i want to import those mysql trigger statements file on my Google Cloud Console database. I am also aware about google console shell to create mysql trigger directly, but instead of writing sql statement using shell command, I want to import it same as database file of sql.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check [Importing Data into Cloud SQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/import-export/importing) and [Triggers cloud sql 2nd generation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39221261/triggers-cloud-sql-2nd-generation).

Comment: yes, it working after enable flag 'log_bin_trust_function_creators ', i re-imported my sql file with triggers. Thanks @wchiquito