# Import MySQL dump into Google SQL - unique_checks=0 is non deterministic

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-sql

I am currently trying to import a mysqldump (~60GB), including triggers and stored procudures, into a google cloud sql database instance.

I have set log_bin_trust_function_creators to true/on with terraform and stripped the DEFINER part from my triggers using perl.

I tried the import using the gcloud sql import function and the web console(import from storage bucket), each time the same error pops up in stackdriver.

severity:  "ERROR"
 textPayload:  "2018-06-26T10:48:42.727799Z 87406 [Warning] Using unique_checks=0 which is non deterministic!"

Afaik unique_checks is set during dumping to speed up the import.
I was not able to find anything on the internet.

Can someone tell me what the error means and how I can fix it?
I would like to avoid dumping the database again because it takes forever.

I must note that i did just use the basic mysqldump without the parameters suggested [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/import-export/creating-sqldump-csv) because i just found the article.

Best regards,

Max

Answer (score 0):

The warning (and not error!) is not directly related to the import of the data, but to how the replication is configured within the target MySQL environment.

As MySQL documentation on [Determination of Safe and Unsafe Statements in Binary Logging](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication-rbr-safe-unsafe.html) says (highlighting is mine):

> The “safeness” of a statement in MySQL replication refers to whether
>   the statement and its effects can be replicated correctly using
>   statement-based format. If this is true of the statement, we refer to
>   the statement as safe; otherwise, we refer to it as unsafe.
>
> **In general, a statement is safe if it deterministic, and unsafe if it
>   is not.**
>
> ...
>
> References to system variables.  **Most system variables are not
>   replicated correctly using the statement-based format.** See Section
>   17.4.1.39, “Replication and Variables”. For exceptions, see Section 5.4.4.3, “Mixed Binary Logging Format”.

`unique_checks=0` sets a system variable and the code probably sets it on global level, which is considered unsafe in statement based replication.

Either change the code to set `unique_checks=0` [on session level](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/using-system-variables.html) (recommended), or [change the binary logging type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/binary-log-setting.html) to `mixed`.

Comment: I am interpreting this a an Error because the import does stop because of this.

Answer (score 0):

There are some [Differences between Cloud SQL and standard MySQL functionality](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/features#differences) which you have to be aware of. The issue here is most probably in the triggers. You can try to disable Binary Logs. Take a look at [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39221261/triggers-cloud-sql-2nd-generation).

However the right approach is to do the MySQL dump following the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/import-export/creating-sqldump-csv) that you mentioned.

If none of the steps above are gonna do the work, please post the errors that you get in logs of the Cloud SQL instance.